# Set width of subcaption box to height of image

Tags: subcaption

I've created a command to streamline my figure creation. I'm working on adding a subcaption (which is really just a `parbox`) using the `subcaption` package that will add some vertical text along the right side of my figure (to say the source of the image).

I've got almost everything done, the only problem is that when I rotate the caption, it extends its width to be as long as the text I pass it. This can cause the figure to be exceptionally tall (See example).

What I need is a way to set the width of the rotated `subcaptionbox` to the height of my image. In my case, I'm setting the width of each image (based on the textwidth), and letting the height of the image follow from the aspect ratio.

[image: Example of figure with long source text]

**What I have tried:** Setting the width of the `subcaptionbox` doesn't work, I'm guessing that it's reset somehow by the `rotatebox`? I have also tried `vphantom` without success. My current code hard sets the width of a `parbox`, but I need it to adjust to the actual height of the image.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\newfigure}[4][]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{demo} %normally the image, here just the demo
        \subcaptionbox*{}[2cm]{
            \rotatebox[origin=t]{90}{
                \parbox{5cm}{ %Should be set variably to the height of the image
                        \scriptsize{#1}
                }
            }
        }
        \caption{#3}
        \label{#4}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
        \newfigure[Source: A potially long and protracted source for the image]{Demo image}{Example caption for the figure}{fig:demo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\subcaptionbox` reserves space for a subcaption below, even if blank.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\nfbox}

\newcommand{\newfigure}[4][]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \savebox\nfbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{demo}}% measure width and height
        \usebox\nfbox
        \subcaptionbox*{}[\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd\nfbox]{%
            \rotatebox[origin=tc]{90}{%
                \parbox{\ht\nfbox}{ %Should be set variably to the height of the image
                        \scriptsize{#1}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
        \caption{#3}
        \label{#4}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
        \newfigure[Source: A potially long and protracted source for the image]{Demo image}{Example caption for the figure}{fig:demo}
\end{document}
```